# E/System: Unable to open boot classpath entry: /system/framework/org.ifaa.android.manager.jar

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following error in the Android Studio while running the app:

> E/System: Unable to open boot classpath entry:/system/framework/org.ifaa.android.manager.jar

Please help me with its solution.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Android studio is still showing this error but now my app is working fine.